# Gaussian Calculations - What is the Basis?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

What am I actually changing when I click 631G(d) or 631G(d,p), etc. when I choose a "basis" in restricted Hartree Fock calculations? What is the difference between using an alternative basis?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [basis set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry)) is used to describe the molecular orbital wave functions.

I suggest reading through a number of links:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry))
- [The Gaussian manual - Basis Sets](http://www.gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/m_basis_sets.htm) - a nice description of the different basis sets, if a bit technical at times.
- [Naming of quantum chemistry basis sets](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/naming-of-quantum-chemistry-basis-sets?rq=1)
- [GAMESS Crash Course](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/16537/5017) - applies to Gaussian or other packages

Comment: Really nice links thank you! I'm still a little confused as to what the "diffuse function" is though.

Comment: In some cases, the electron distribution is far from the nucleus. A great example is $\ce{H-}$, where the extra electron is really diffuse. So a "diffuse function" might be a very large "s" or "p" function to describe the wave function far from the nucleus.

Comment: Diffuse functions are critical when dealing with anions (among other situations) since the extra electrons are usually.. well, *diffuse.*

Comment: ah thank you I see now, its just how spread out the electron density is then? It seems though that if I change the Basis set to whatever I want I will get a different answer for the energies, how do we know which to trust, let alone which programme?

Comment: @RedPen If you're using Hartree Fock, you can use the [variational principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)), which clarifies that the lower the energy, the closer to the "true" correct total energy. In general, you use the largest basis set you have time to use, e.g. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7920/suggest-methods-and-basis-sets-for-a-variety-of-systems?rq=1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll read over these links over the next few days and see if anything comes up I don't quite understand :)